# Unselectable items in a Combo Box in an Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have a combo box (in a user form in Excel) whose data source is set of menu items with headers (a named range in a worksheet). Right now, my workaround is to erase these headers (e.g. Main Course, Desserts, Beverages, etc.) but I would still like to know if it's possible to add these unselectable headers so that the end user has distinctions between the different menu items. Any help would be very much appreciated :)

e.g.

```
Main Courses (**unselectable**)
Roast Beef with Mashed Potato (selectable)
Spicy Spareribs (selectable)
Beef Stroganoff (selectable)
Roast Chicken (selectable)
Desserts (**unselectable**)
Mango Float (selectable)
Brownies (selectable)
Lemon Squares (selectable)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No AFAIK, you can't do that. Below are two alternatives. Take your pick :)

**Alternative 1**

Deselect the moment user selects the relevant header. For example

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.Style = fmStyleDropDownList
    ComboBox1.AddItem "---  Main Courses ---"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Roast Beef with Mashed Potato"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Spicy Spareribs"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "---  Desserts  ---"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Mango Float"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Brownies"
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
    Select Case ComboBox1.Value
    Case "---  Main Courses ---", "---  Desserts  ---"
        ComboBox1.Value = ""
    End Select
End Sub
```

**Alternative 2**

Use two comboboxes. One for the header and the other for the different menu items. Simply populate the second combobox based on the selection of the first combobox. For example

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.Style = fmStyleDropDownList
    ComboBox2.Style = fmStyleDropDownList
    ComboBox1.AddItem "---  Main Courses ---"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "---  Desserts  ---"
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
    ComboBox2.Clear

    Select Case ComboBox1.Value
    Case "---  Main Courses ---"
        ComboBox2.AddItem "Roast Beef with Mashed Potato"
        ComboBox2.AddItem "Spicy Spareribs"
    Case "---  Desserts  ---"
        ComboBox2.AddItem "Mango Float"
        ComboBox2.AddItem "Brownies"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Also to be on a safer side, use the `ComboBox1_Change` event.

Answer (score 1):

A bit behind but I found this is extremely simple and works fantastic!

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     If ComboBox1.Value = "---------------" Then
         Exit Sub
     End If
End Sub
```

This is in the case your ComboBox is on a UserForm, like mine. I have the item I do not want selected as "------------" as a separator between list items. If it is selected, then the UserForm cannot be submitted.